# Importing Training Data in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I previously built a CNN using ml5.js. I've migrated to TensorFlow.js, due to its extensive documentation and additional features.

I'm new to TensorFlow, and still trying to understand how to build a CNN. **I'm stuck at the very first step: importing my training data.** My training data is subdivided into three directories: Linear, Quadratic, and Cubic. My training data consists of 1000 sample images for each of these classes, for a total of 3000 images. Below is a schematic of the organization of my training data:
[image]

In ml5.js, I imported my training data for the three classes using a `for loop`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    linearSinusoidal[i] = loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../LineSine_'+str(i)+'.png');
    quadraticSinusoidal[i] = loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../QuadSine_'+str(i)+'.png');
    cubicSinusoidal[i] = loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../CubicSine_'+str(i)+'.png');
  }
```

In TensorFlow, the documentation provides the following example of importing training data from a .tgz file to train a Image Classification CNN:

```
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

However, my data is not in a .tgz file. Nor is it stored locally -- all my training data is online on GitHub. I've looked at the documentation, tutorials, and other Q&As, but I'm still stuck.

If anyone can help me understand how to import my training data into TensorFlow, that would be great.Thank you.

Comment: Run your code in google colab, then clone your repo using colab and you will have all your files availables to run your model

Comment: @FreddyDaniel OK, a step-by-step example would really help, but in the meantime, I'm trying on my own.

Comment: Run something like this in colab `!git clone https://github.com/myuser/repo_name.git` get your url of the repo and make `!git clone <url_repo>` you will have your files in colab.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel OK. After running `!git clone https://github.com/Refath/SinusoidalAnalyzer.git`, I get `fatal: destination path 'SinusoidalAnalyzer' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: Press the reload or update button to see the new directory in colab..